# NameError: name 'read_image' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I want to test my image classification model with a image. 
But I get some error:

```
 --> path = 'E:/My Work Elements/Thesis Related/Trash Classification/Trash New Code/test/cardboard/cardboard42.jpg'
    test_single_image(path)
        Traceback (most recent call last):

          File "<ipython-input-15-4a6021aada0c>", line 2, in <module>
            test_single_image(path)

          File "<ipython-input-14-1654f8f7a46b>", line 3, in test_single_image
            images = read_image(path)

        NameError: name 'read_image' is not defined
```

I use this code:

```
def test_single_image(path):
  Garbage = ['cardboard','Glass','Metal','paper','plastic','Trash']
  images = read_image(path)
  time.sleep(.5)
  bt_prediction = vgg16.predict(images) 
  preds = model.predict_proba(bt_prediction)
  for idx, Garbage, x in zip(range(0,6), Garbage , preds[0]):
   print("ID: {}, Label: {} {}%".format(idx, Garbage, round(x*100,2) ))
  print('Final Decision:')
  time.sleep(.5)
  for x in range(3):
   print('.'*(x+1))
   time.sleep(.2)
  class_predicted = model.predict_classes(bt_prediction)
  class_dictionary = generator_top.class_indices
  print(class_dictionary)
  inv_map = {v: k for k, v in class_dictionary.items()} 
  print("Class: {}, prediction Result: {}".format(class_predicted[0], inv_map[class_predicted[0]])) 
  return load_img(path, target_size=(224,224))

path = 'E:/My Work Elements/Thesis Related/Trash Classification/Trash New Code/test/cardboard/cardboard42.jpg'
test_single_image(path)
```

How do I fix the code?

Comment: Where did you define `read_image` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the keras VGG16 API to get the VGG16 model easily

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

features = model.predict(x)
```

you `read_image` method change to the `load_image` method. The keras API will resize the image to met the vgg16 model request.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using opencv to read an image it is supposed to be cv2.imread(). as far as i used vgg16 there should be a read_image function defined before which takes in the image of any shape, resize's it into standard shape (224*224*3) and does any other type of preprocessing required.

If you are using keras preprocessing it has a predefined load_img function which does the preprocessing for you .

example :

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
load_image(path,target_size= (224*224*3))
```

my sample load function

```
from keras.preprocessing import image 
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions, preprocess_input
def load_image(path): 
  img = image.load_img(path,target_size=model.input_shape[1:3]) 
  x = image.img_to_array(img) 
  x = np.expand_dims(x,axis=0) 
  x = preprocess_input(x) 
  return img,x
```

Comment: can you show me your VGG16 model . where " read_image " should be defined ? 
I am new in machine learning. That's why i am asking. thanks